# Can I use Vagrant for Production Environments

Tags: vagrant

This week I start playing with Vagrant and Docker. And I'm really excited with all the concept.

There is anyone using Vagrant in Production Environments or is just used to maintain images of development machines?

Comment: Erm...it says specifically it's designed for *development* environments. So, no.

Comment: what would you want to use it in production for ? It's backed for virtualbox.

Comment: @Sirex Vagrant has several backends other than VirtualBox now, though most of them require you pay for the commercial product.

Comment: oh, news to me. cool.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390483/vagrant-in-production

Comment: I'm talking about Vagrant and Docker, that is something different than the question that you make reference. Another opinion this is one tipical question for ServerFault not for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't recommend it for any environment that needs availability or will be managed by more than one person.

While it can control production environments there are several changes you would want to make before doing so.  You will want to change the default vagrant auth information and probably use a different back end.

One major drawback is that there is not shared state.  Management would need to be one one host that could not go down.  If the management host dies or is rebooted you loose all state information.

I use it to prototype production configurations and provide these to other team members.  This allows us to have environments that are the same in everything except scale for dev, QA, staging, demos, and production.  Combined with Chef or Puppet this is very effective for this job.

TL;DR This is not a good idea.